# How do I delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, windows-domain

How can I delete the local user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is connected to a Windows Server 2008 domain?

[DelProf](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5405) doesn't seem to exist on Windows 7.

Comment: Rename the folder in users first

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can do it with the User Profiles dialog in System Properties:

- Log in as different user (with admin privileges) than you want to delete
- Open Properties for Computer
- Advanced system settings (on the left side)
- Settings for User Profiles (in the middle)
- Select the profile you want to delete and click the delete button

[image: Deleting local user profiles]

Comment: Does the command delete only preferences or it also deletes documents?

Comment: @PauloAvelar I second this

Comment: I am following the steps above,  but for the specific profile that I am trying to delete - the delete button is disable. What could be the reason for this? I have logged into an account different from the one that I want to delete.

Answer (score 36):

To clear user local profile via registry:

1. Click Start → Run → Regedit
2. Navigate to the following registry key :`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
3. Under ProfileList navigate to binary key’s like this: `S-1-5-21-3656904587-1668747452-4095529-500`
4. On the right side under **ProfileImagePath** you'll see the profile path.
5. Chose the one with the desired user and delete the long registry key like: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

You will then need to either rename (preferable), or delete the user profile on disk under `C:\Users\%username%`

Comment: This official Microsoft [KB156826](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/156826/how-to-disable-and-delete-user-profiles) confirms what you're saying, but goes further saying you can remove `ProfileList` key in regedit to delete ALL profiles if you desire which is a little surprising to me!

Answer (score 18):

I have developed an unofficial successor to Microsoft's Delprof called [Delprof2](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/). It is syntax compatible to the original but more powerful.

Comment: Great piece of software!

Comment: Fantastic! Have been looking for a delprof replacement.

Comment: Hi Helge, I tested your tool but there is a problem about "not old enough" user thing. The antivirus scan make 1 year old users seems that is active. Is something I'm missing or we can't do anything about it?

Answer (score 7):

GPO: Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ System \ User Profiles
This seems the perfect answer for deleting old domain users[image]

Comment: there was a bug that has been fixed by microsoft 
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983544