# How can I reset my own roaming profile on Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, roaming-profiles

My University uses Windows 7 professional roaming profiles with a domain. I'm not entirely sure how it works, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Is there a way I can reset my profile to its vanilla "out of the box" state for a new account? I've tried deleting pretty much every file I have write permissions on, but things in AppData like my Firefox profile, start-menu ordering etc all seem to get restored when I log back in.

Is this possible, or should I just ask the administrator? All the resources I've found have been for administrators to reset users profiles, not for users to reset their own.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? What is your end-goal?

Answer (score 0):

With a roaming profile, your data is copied down from the server when you log in and (depending on organisational policy) copied back when you log out. It may also be configured to sync in the background.

Without access to the server you can't remove the server copy of your profile. But thinking about it, your user has permission to write to it so you could probably empty the folder...

You can find where your profile is stored on the server and open that path with windows explorer to delete the remote version. Doing it this way, you would need to empty the local and remote versions. You may even have to hard-power off the computer to stop it from trying to put anything back.

There's also stuff stored in the registry. Overall, to delete cleanly you need to follow this procedure by logging in as a different user (with administrative privileges): [How do I delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain) You would have to have emptied the server copy first.

That said, it's probably just easier to ask your network administrator!

Comment: The user profile simply reports as C:\Users\Foo. I know the remote location is \\servername\profiles\foo, and I can delete both, but something is putting it back when I sign back in. Including my Downloads folder, weirdly, but not my Documents, Pictures etc.

Comment: That is weird. It sounds more like a mandatory profile, so you would receive the same profile every time regardless. Your Documents, Pictures, etc are probably redirected elswehere (like your home folder) is it possible your downloads are redirected too?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: do not delete the two folders without deleting data from system registry; the risk is to  be forced to use a temporary profile each time you sign it

Comment: Rather than logging in as a different user, try the fix-all solution: REIMAGE THE COMPUTER!

Comment: @InterLinked and the server!?

Comment: @john I am referring specifically to the second to last paragraph in your answer - not the rest of it. As far as giving your machine a fresh start, reimaging the computer is always the first thing to do. In a good network setup, a computer should be able to be reimaged anytime and very little productivity should be lost

Comment: @InterLinked once upon a time, I would have agreed with you, but it's not always as straightforward as that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting questions on this site why not ask the people who manage your account and the server that stores your account: **The IT Department**

Just explain to them you are having login issues with the roaming profile and either

1. Want to have roaming profiles turned off for your account
2. Or you want to have the roaming profile cleaned out.

As for the part where you say it keeps "reappearing" its likely you dont have delete permissions on that share but have write (so the profile only grows)
or they have an auto backup that keeps the profile from being deleted by a non-system admin