# Verify and fix user folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

I got a fresh PC with Windows 7. Unaware of things I went straight to "clean-up" my user directory. I deleted all "My *" folders (documents, videos, etc.). I experienced some nasty bug with Outlook that was caused by the lack of "My Documents".

With some magic I was able to recreate the junction point for "My Documents".

I'd like to delete the user and recreate it, but I cannot do it on this machine.

Is there a way to verify that all the default folders are there and the junction points are correct? I want to avoid nasty surprises in the future.

Comment: Why are you unable to delete and recreate the user exactly?

Comment: Since you've said it's a fresh install, I'd say just format and start over; only this time don't go deleting stuff willy-nilly. :)

Comment: It's a company pc. I have administrator priviliges though.

Comment: Is it possible that the IT guys have preped the PC with Windows 7 via Deployment tool? Is the PC part of the domain? (Check techie007 answer) Are you sure you can be "deleting stuff willy-nilly" on work PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the registry key for the profile, reboot, and log in again.

This should cause Windows to rebuild your profile on that PC, and any missing folders.

Before doing this, I would backup any data to another local location (c:\backup) as well as exporting a backup of the registry key just in case.

Here's how to remove the local user profile via the registry:

> Click on Start > Run > `regedit` > <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>
> Navigate to the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
>
> Under `ProfileList` navigate to binary keys like this: `S-1-5-21-3656904587-1668747452-4095529-500`
>
> On the right side under `ProfileImagePath` you will see the profile
>   path.
>
> Choose the one with the desired user and delete the long registry key
>   corresponding to your username - it will look like this:
>
> [image]

Comment: Don't delete without backup if the hives have been modified.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say it's a company computer and that's why you can't recreate the user, I'm guessing you're on a domain, using domain credentials to log in.

In that case you don't need to delete/recreate the actual user, just the user's profile on the computer in question:

- Log in as a different (administrative) user.
- Delete the questionable user profile (See: [How do I delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain?rq=1))
- Log back in as that user to create a new profile on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user, see what all the default folders are on a new user, make sure that they all exist in your current profile. Should be all there is to it.