# Set a default tile arrangment on the Windows 8.1 start menu

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a few Windows 8.1 computers. They are joined to a domain, and will be shared among multiple users. I want to provide a default arrangement for the tiles on the Windows 8 start menu.

I know I can do this through group policy, but that locks the arrangement in place; it becomes mandatory, rather than simply the default or original layout for each profile. I only want to provide a default that users can change later.

I also want to include a shortcut that I made myself in this layout, and it needs to include an item that's based on network access that is not available to the local administrator account.

How can I get a start menu layout that accomplishes all this?

Comment: the layout is stored in a file called **appsFolder.itemdata-ms**. copy the file to c:\users\default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows and set it to readonly.

Comment: @magicandre1981 You're saying to do this in one profile, and then copy the one from my profile to do the default profile?

Comment: correct, this is the way to create that file

Comment: I've created an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I had to do to get everything I wanted to work:

1. I had to log in as a standard user, because I wanted my layout to reference some network resources that were not available for the local administrator account.
2. Setup the layout like you want

   If you want to include a shortcut file that you make yourself, ie to a shared folder:

   1. Make the shortcut, and place it in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`
   2. The item should now appear in Start Menu's `Apps` view (swipe up from the bottom, or click the down arrow below the regular start menu)
   3. Pin the shortcut to the start menu from the Apps view.
   4. Pinning from anywhere else will not work. Pinning from the Apps view if the file is not saved in that common ProgramData location will not work.

   .
3. Copy `appFolder.itemdata-ms` from `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows` to the equivalent folder for the Default profile (usually `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows`) You may need to provide administrator credentials to do this, or you may want to do this between step 7 and step 8, instead.
4. While still logged in as the user where you prepare the start menu layout, use Powershell to export your layout, like this:

   > Export-StartLayout -As BIN -Path appsFolderLayout.bin

   The file will be in your Documents library.
5. Copy it to the equivalent folder for the Default user (possibly this is not necessary, but I had done this when I finally got it to work). Again, you may want to do this step in between steps 7 and 8.
6. Also copy it to the root folder of the local administrator's profile (ie: `C:\Users\Administrator\`)
7. Login with the local administrator account.
8. Run PowerShell as administrator
9. Execute the following command:

   > Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath .\appsFolderLayout.bin -MountPath \

   Note the trailing back-slash.
10. [Delete any user profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain) on the system where you need to see the new layout
11. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

The layout is stored in a file called **appsFolder.itemdata-ms**. Use one Account to create the layout in the way you want it and copy the layout file to **c:\users\default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows** and set it to readonly.

In Windows 8.1 there is also new a [powershell command to export the layout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283401.aspx):

```
Export-StartLayout -Path "C:\Layouts\Marketing.bin" -As BIN
```

You can later use the Import [cmdlet to import it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283403.aspx).

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this today, and it didn't work :/ I copied from the appsFolder.itemdata-ms file from my template profile to the default profile, logged in as a new user, and did not see my adjusted layout.

Comment: have you set the file to readonly? Have you tried the DISM way to import the layout?

Comment: Readonly didn't help. I don't have an image in this case. I need to get this working on an already-installed system.

Comment: Have you tried the DISM command?

Comment: I haven't, but I'm not sure how it will help: there is no image to mount here except the currently running system, and I didn't think dism could work on that system?

Comment: the command works on the current running Windows

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I follow most of [this guide](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c7a75c34-767a-404a-a0a1-daa4a978f5a1/using-importstartlayout-to-a-local-system?forum=winserverpowershell), but I notice the special emphasis on importing to the default profile. Isn't that where it always imports? What do I have to do special to import to the default profile?

Comment: Haha, I got it! Looks like I need to do BOTH the Import-Layout _and_ copy the appsFolder.itemdata-ms file, and make sure both that file and AppsFolderLayout.bin file are waiting in the default profile when done.

Comment: Hmm... almost. My custom layout included a shortcut to a shared drive. That shortcut is one of the big reasons I need to do this, and it doesn't show up. Still, that's a new issue now. This worked well enough for upvote + accept.

Comment: Thanks for this, you set me on the path. But I eventually needed to make enough tweaks that I felt I needed to provide my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Adding another method on how to take some of the above and do it via Group Policy

http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthewms/archive/2014/03/21/windows-8-1-for-business-remember-our-good-friend-group-policy.aspx

Comment: As I indicated in the question, the Group Policy method is **NOT** okay for this, because it _locks_ the arrangement and prevents users from making changes, rather than simply providing a default.