# Email account gets reset when pc restart

Tags: networking, email, microsoft-outlook-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I have multiple PCs connected to a domain through network (Windows Server 2012R2).
On one of my PC, every time when i restart the Desktop, my email account configured in MS office Outlook 2013 gets deleted which means i have to reconfigure same account each time the PC restart.

When the PC restarts one popup message `You've been signed in with a temporary profile` appears.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the profile is corrupt for the user.

Log in as domain administrator or local administrator on that PC.

Go to c:\user\ and rename the user account to add a _old at the end.

Go to Start Menu > type in regedit and load the Windows registry, go to this area of the registry hive:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\
```

Find the user in the list of profile GUID's you should be able to click down the list and find the one that correlates to the users path c:\users\xxx once found delete the key from the registry.

Log out of the administrator account and back in as the user, you should now get a new profile and not a temporary one. You can copy back any data from the c:\users\xxxx_old\ path things like desktop, my docs, etc.

Create outlook profile and give it a reboot, should now be ok.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason for profile corrupt so that i may avoid it next time?

Comment: No problem glad it worked... Various reasons to be honest.. I've seen the ntuser.dat file get corrupt, permission changes on the user folder, etc. Sometimes users might cause it by turning off the machine without logging out for example however I think generally its just something that happens with Windows I've never been able to avoid it 100% myself it crops up now and then everywhere I've worked...

Comment: How do I delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain? http://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain