# "Recycled user" creates C:\Users\TEMP on logon

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008

An employee left, and was replaced by another to fill the exact same position. Since this employee used the exact same permissions on the network, had no personal files on the local C:, I just renamed the account on the Primary Domain Controller<del>, deleted the local account on the machine</del>, and deleted the user's local folder (i.e. inside `C:\Users`)

However, now when I logon with that "recycled" (renamed) user, Windows create `C:\Users/TEMP` every time.

How do I tell Windows not to do that and create the proper user's directory?

---

#### Edit

The user is not member of "Guest" or "Domain Guest".

Comment: Wait, so is it a local account or a domain account? You kind of said it was both at first.

Comment: It is a domain account, and since I renamed it, it still logged on using the old `C:\Users\xxxx` directory. So I tried deleting that directory, thinking Windows would re-create it with the new domain account's user name... but it created `C:\Users\TEMP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deleting the folder is not how you remove a user profile from a Windows PC; so you've corrupted the profile and as such it's loading a temporary profile instead.

For information on how to properly remove a domain-based user profile, and how to clean up a half-deleted profile, see this existing SU question: [How do I delete a user profile on a Windows 7 machine that is part of a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/63017/how-do-i-delete-a-user-profile-on-a-windows-7-machine-that-is-part-of-a-domain)

Comment: I figured. However, as a Linux user, and analyst programmer, I am mainly an improvised IT, using an already messed-up setup from some other IT firm, back a few years before I was hired (i.e. even to my limited sysadmin experience, what I need to work with is crap, and I already made several security adjustments, and am planning a major upgrade next year, hiring a competent firm for that, of course!)

Anyhow. you suggested answer **does** work, but [this](http://superuser.com/a/140814/41727) is what resolved my issue (also found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2454362)). Thanks!